# datagridview property box display blank in windows application 2008

Tags: datagridview

I  have face a problems that DataGridView1 property box showing blank in our windows application 2008.
and also in another windows form datagridview1 property box showing blank.
so please tell me to resolve this issues.

```
                    string qryproceedip = "Select COUNT(ProceedIP)TotalIPCounts,convert(time(7), DateAdd(SECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,(worktime),(deletetime))),0),108) as actualtime " +
                    " from ipinfo where username='" + username.Trim() + "' and workdate='" + todaylogindate.Trim() + "'";
                   SqlCommand cmdip = new SqlCommand(qryproceedip, mycon);
                   mycon.Open();
                   SqlDataAdapter sdaip = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdip);
                   DataTable dtip = new DataTable();
                   sdaip.Fill(dtip);
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dtip;
                   mycon.Close();
                   dtip.Clear();
                   tdt.Clear();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M90B.png)

Comment: adding more information to what you have tried, and the code you've used may help isolate the exact problem.  perhaps even attaching an image (a link is acceptable)

Comment: You're filling a `DataTable` with data, binding it to the `DataSource`, then you *clear* the `DataTable`. It's blank because you told it to be.